# Checking the value of a Lua stack item from C++

Tags: c++, lua, stack

how do I check the value of the top of the stack in Lua?

I have the following C++ code:

```
if (luaL_loadfile(L, filename) == NULL) {
        return 0;// error..
    }

    lua_pcall(L,0,0,0); // execute the current script..

    lua_getglobal(L,"variable");

    if (!lua_isstring(L,-1)){ // fails this check..
        lua_pop(L,1);
        return 0; // error
}
```

The contents of the file in question is

```
-- A comment
variable = "MyString"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely problem is that [`luaL_loadfile()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadfile) is documented to return the same values as [`lua_load()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_load) or one additional error code. In either case, the return value is an `int` where 0 means success and a nonzero value is an error code.

So, the test `luaL_loadfile(...) == NULL` is **true** if the file was loaded, but the code calls that an error and returns.

The function `lua_pcall()` also returns a status code, and you may want to verify that as well.

Otherwise, the script as shown does create a global variable, and `lua_getglobal()` would retrieve that to the stack where it could be tested with `lua_isstring()`, or probably more usefully let you return its value if it is sufficiently string-like with [`lua_tostring()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_tostring). The latter function will return either a `const char *` pointing at a nul-terminated string, or NULL if the value at the stack index can't be converted to a string. See the Lua reference manual as linked for the rest of the details and a caveat about using `lua_tostring()` inside a loop.

**Edit:** I added better links to the manual in a couple of places.

Comment: Will follow this trail and update you on the result, thanks! :D

Comment: Well, it seems like you were on the right track.. luaL_loadfile returns 6.. What does it mean? Where can I find the list of error codes for this? Thanks..

Comment: nvm, figured it out, thanks to you :) I was passing in the wrong filename and it couldn't open it.. Needed the fully qualified path name..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace luaL_loadfile with [lua_dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/2.4/node14.html). lua_pcall is unnecessary. My guess is loading a file as a function using luaL_loadfile and then running it using pcall may not create the globals you want.

Comment: No, lua_dofile loads the file and runs it. I want to do them separately. Am I using loadfile and pcall incorrectly?